# Завершение выполнения функции после выполнения условия внутри неё

Tags: html, jquery, html5

Суть: есть окно с вопросом и вариантами ответа, у которых один и тот же класс; при выборе одного из вариантов, в зависимости от наличия у него нужного id, выполняется одно из условий.

Нужно: после выполнения одного из условий, отключить обработку клика по остальным вариантам. Пробовал через смену класса на disabled, всё равно обработка продолжается. При этом, после закрытия и повторного открытия этого окна функция снова должна работать, так что .on() и .off() тут не подойдут.

```
$('.answer').click( function(){
    if ($(this).is('#true')){
        $(this).css({'background':'green'});
        $('.answer').toggleClass('disabled answer');
    }
    else{
        $(this).css({'background':'red'});
        $('.answer').toggleClass('disabled answer');
    }
});
$('.close').click(function(){
    $('.questionBg').css({'display':'none'});
    $('.disabled').attr('style','').toggleClass('answer disabled');
});
```

```
<div class="questionBg">
    <div class="questionBlock">
        <div class="question">
            <img src="image/question.png">
        </div>
        <div class="questionText">
            Какого цвета этот блок?
        </div>
        <ul class="answers">
            Варианты ответа:
            <li class="answer">Синий</li>
            <li class="answer">Красный</li>
            <li class="answer">Серый</li>
            <li class="answer" id="true">Белый</li>
        </ul>
        <button class="close">
            <img src="icons/cross.png">
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

думаю, что так. Вот тут про [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

```
$(this).off('click');
```

Comment: А как мне потом заставить эту же функцию работать при повторном открытии окна?

Comment: так она опять назначится вот этим `$('.answer').click( function(){`

Comment: проблема в том, что окно это - часть страницы, и после его закрытия перезагрузки страницы не произойдёт

Comment: в обработку события открытия окна добавьте включение обработчиков клика

Comment: ок, спасибо, попробую

Comment: т.е. по-сути внутрь    $('.tablecell').click(function()    прописать    $('.answer').on('click');    ?

Comment: `$('.answer').on('click', имя_функции);` или саму функцию там объявить

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.answer').click( function(){
  if ($(this).hasClass("disabled"))
    return;
  ...
```